# solve the puzzle

Tags: puzzle

I have recently encountered a reasoning question that I have solved half , but I can't solve one part of it. Question : 
\begin{align*}
 3 + 5 + 6 &= 152092\\
 7 + 6 + 5 &= 422416\\
 4 + 7 + 5 &= 282694
\end{align*}

I could figure out that ,in the first , 1st * 2nd (3 * 5) equals first two digits of the answer (15). This applies for all the other. But I can't figure out how the last four digits are formed in each.

Please tell me how are the last four digits are formed.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Let the question be $x + y + z =  abcdef$. Throughout, multiplication will strictly be represented by $\times$, and concatenation of variables corresponds to concatenation of digits.

As you note, $x \times y = ab$.

$cd = x+y+z+a+b$.

$fe = ab + cd - z$.